# Infinite loop while selecting item from spinner

Tags: java, android

I have a language spinner and when selected respective language, with `set.locale` it changes the language of the app. However, I get an infinite loop when clicking on an element inside spinner and it refreshes the activity after language change all time. I guess when the item is selected it reads the selected item unlimited times. What's the error and how to solve the problem? Thank you

```
package com.example.mher.citygo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Locale;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        String[] items;
        private static final int REQUEST_CALL=1;
        ArrayList<String> listItems;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        ListView listView;
        EditText editText;
        Button bregister;
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ArrayList<ItemData> list=new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(new ItemData("Eng",R.drawable.usaflag));
            list.add(new ItemData("Arm",R.drawable.armeniaflag));
            list.add(new ItemData("Ru",R.drawable.russiaflag));
            list.add(new ItemData("Per",R.drawable.iranflag));
            Spinner sp=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            SpinnerAdapter adapter=new SpinnerAdapter(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.txt,list);
            sp.setAdapter(adapter);

            sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if(position==0)
                        setLocale("ru");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });





            final Button SearchARid=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bSearchRide);
            Button LoginDriver=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin_As_A_Driver);
            bregister=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);



            bregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent SignUp=new Intent(MainActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(SignUp);

                }
            });

            LoginDriver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent DriverLogin=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(DriverLogin);
                }
            });

            SearchARid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent SearchRide=new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchRide.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(SearchRide);
                }
            });
        }
        public void setLocale(String lang) {
            Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
            Resources res = getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.locale = myLocale;
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(refresh);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onItemSelected()` is not only called when the *user* makes a selection. It is called when *anything* makes a selection, which includes setting the default selection. A `Spinner` always has a selection; if you do not specify otherwise, `Spinner` selects the first item in your adapter.

In your case, you respond to `onItemSelected()` by destroying and recreating the activity, which triggers a call to `onItemSelected()`, which destroys and recreates the activity, which triggers a call to `onItemSelected()`, and so on.

You need to ignore the first `onItemSelected()` event, which will be setting the initial selection. The second event (if any) will be from the user.

Comment: And how to do it ?

Comment: @KarenMkhitaryan: Well, you could use a `boolean` field (e.g., `isFirstEvent`), initially set to `true`. In your `onItemSelected()` method, check that `boolean` and see whether it is the first event or not.

Comment: Your solution is right but when I do so and selecting another item and then selecting the first, first one doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Before `setOnItemSelectedListener` you can write the following line to fix your issue

```
// prevent go to OnItemSelectedListener on create activity, ONLY when user select
sp.setSelection(0,false);
```